# player stuck to wall with 0 friction, tilemap problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am coding a small platformer in unity and have the issue that my player is stuck to the wall wenn pressing against it.

I found various solutions like the "physics material 2d" and tried them, but they only work until my player slides down to the next part of the grid/tilemap. when it reaches the top of the next tilemap wallpiece it gets stuck, even when i get off the key.

Comment: Hello, it would be nice if you could share the code related to the player's movement, along with the references to the attempts you have tried.

Comment: so i tried a second box collider on the charakter, wider but smaller, with zero friction. that actually worked when i placed a normal 2d rectangle sprite but won´t work for my tilemap smh.

Comment: `  void Update()
    {
        float richtung = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * moveSpeed * richtung * Time.deltaTime);

        if (isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
`